# Remove artifacts from Nexus repository

Tags: repository, nexus

I deployed some artifacts and I copy-pasted wrong name of those artifacts. I remember that manual playing with repository content brings problems.

What is the recommended way for dealing with these situations?

EDITED:

I thought there was no way of deleting artifacts from hosted repositories via web interface. Now I see that in the "Browse storage" section I can delete the artifact directory, which is the the recommended way I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the edit note. "Browse storage"  is definitely it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yup, in the past I've just deleted artifacts using the web GUI, no problems

Comment: Problem is that the `.sha1` and `.md5` files are left behind if you don't delete the artifacts through the repository interface.

Comment: and if you delete snapshot versions, they remain listed in maven-metadata.xml for the artifact; if listed as the latest version, trying to retrieve it will give you an error

Comment: @Dr.Z that problem can be fixed by creating a scheduled job that rebuilds the metadata files. This is the only effective solution to a number of problems related to snapshots.

Answer (score 20):

login as administrator, delete the artifacts you want to remove, and rebuild index for this repo.
[image: delete all artifacts in a repository]
[image: rebuild index for a repository]

Comment: Does not work with proxied public artifacts (e.g. from maven-central).

Answer (score 7):

On my installation (Nexus 3.23, with a Python repository), the "delete component" isn't available in the WebGUI from the browse interface (even logged in as local admin).

However, if you use the "Advanced search" feature and select the desired component/package, then the delete function is available, so it's the only way I found to delete a package.

Comment: I found the same. However, I find that deleting components this way leaves the manifests in the repo, even after I do a Rebuild Index via Configuration -> Repositories -> {repository name} -> Rebuild index

Answer (score 0):

In Nexus 2, you can right-click on the element and select "Delete":

[image]

Answer (score -2):

1)click on settings
2)click on Repositories
3)click on the Repository that you wish to delete
4)click on delete Repository on the top left corner
5)Repository will be deleted

Comment: If you are wondering why your answer gets down-voted: OP asked how he can delete *artifacts* in a repository, not the repository itself.