# Maven download Artifact form Nexus is endless

Tags: maven, nexus3

I have strange behavior with maven. During my build, the download of the json-smart metadata component (the only artifact that seems to be affected by this problem) loops without ever stopping.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< fr.project:myProject >----------------
[INFO] Building Ned MyProject 1.8.2
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from nexus: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
```

If I pour central maven repo directly it's OK but if I use our Nexus, the problem is still there.

- I check certificat, they are OK I check nexus log, there is nothing
  about this download Maven Log in debug show nothing elses (just this
  final command)
- I have use -U and udpatePolicy command in maven setting but nothing ([When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of))
- I have clean all json-smart artifact form maven-central repo of our
  nexus and task a clean metadata but nothing([Remove artifacts from Nexus repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692681/remove-artifacts-from-nexus-repository) and [how to force sonatype nexus 3 to recreate maven-metadata.xml for maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837525/how-to-force-sonatype-nexus-3-to-recreate-maven-metadata-xml-for-maven-repositor))

I have no other ideas, has anyone as one ?

Apache Maven 3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.3, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Nexus : 3.6.0-02

Comment: Which Maven versions/JDK versions etc. are you using? Furthermore have you recreated the meta data in your nexus... ? Also which version of Nexus do you use?

Comment: I have add them on the main thread

Comment: The nexus version is very old (current one 3.37.3)...... (check the release notes of the newer ones in particular related to metadata generation) also Maven is a bit old... (3.8.4)...

Comment: Upgrade first...

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution but no explication on the real problem.

metadata of our json-smart artefact were corrupted on our Nexus and block download from maven. I have delete all composant, invalidate cache of the repository and rebuilt the index and it's seem resolve the problem.

Comment: How to delete components (.xml too) in nexus with this version?  we use nexus 3.8 and we have this problem.